# Cannot run program .class or .java is not a valid win32 application

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a main program while running another main program. When I use a class to execute a program I run into a io exception that says...

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Test.class": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at Execute.f(Execute.java:43)
        at Execute.run(Execute.java:63)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

I understand that the class is not an executable. But why is that when in command prompt I can run a program, but I can run another program while in a program. I can't tell if I'm just not typing in the command prompt correctly. Or my program is incorrect. The following code is the class I'm trying to run from another main class. I can run an executable like notepad and arguments for notepad. But I can't run another main class program that I created.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Execute extends Thread{
private String name;

  public Execute(String name){
      if(name.length() != 0)
      {
          this.name = name;
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println("No file was entered");
      return;
      }
  }


  private void f(){
      String[] split = name.split(" ");
      File f = new File(split[0]);
      for(String k: split)
          System.out.println(k);
      if(f.isFile())
      {
          if(f.canExecute())
             {
              try{
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec(split);
              System.out.println("program has ran");
              }catch(IOException e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
             }
          else if(!f.canExecute())
          {
              System.out.println(name + " is not an exectuable");
              return;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println(name + " Is not a file");
      }
   }
  public void run()
  {
      f();
  }
}
```

The next class is one that give me an error when I try to run it.

```
public class Test extends Thread{

public static int n;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(args[0] + " " + args[1] + " " + args[2]);
    n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  } 
  private static int f(int n){
      System.out.println("FFFF");
    if(n <= 0) return 1;
    else return n * f(n-1);
  }

  public void run()
  {
    f(n);
  }
}
```

exec Test.java (with arguments)and
exec Test.class (with arguments) give me the same error

This is the main class used to run exec.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      while(true){
        System.out.print("PROMPT\\>");
        String command = "";
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
          command = stdin.readLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
          return;
        }
        StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(command);
        if (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
          Token token = new Token(tok.nextToken());
          String s = "";
          while (tok.hasMoreTokens())
            s = s + " " + tok.nextToken();
          if (!s.equals(""))
            s = s.substring(1);
          switch (token.kind) {
            case Token.ATTRIB: //done
             Thread t1 = new Thread(new Attrib(s)); //done
             t1.start();
             try{t1.join();}
             catch(InterruptedException io)
             {
                 io.printStackTrace();
             }
             break;

            case Token.COPY: //done
             t1 = new Thread(new Copy(s));
             t1.start();
             try{t1.join();}
             catch(InterruptedException io)
             {
                 io.printStackTrace();
             }
             break;

            case Token.DATE: //done
              t1 = new Thread(new MyDate());
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.DELETE: //done
              t1 = new Thread(new Delete(s));
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.DIR: //done
              t1 = new Thread(new Dir(s));
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.EDIT: //done
              t1 = new Thread(new Notepad());
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.EXEC: //done
              t1 = new Thread(new Execute(s));
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.EXIT: //done
              System.exit(1);

            case Token.MKDIR: //done
              t1 = new Thread(new Mkdir(s));
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.RENAME: //done
              t1 = new Thread(new Rename(s));
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.RMDIR: //done
              t1 = new Thread(new Rmdir(s));
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.TIME:  //done
              t1 = new Thread(new MyTime());
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                 io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.PRODUCER:
              t1 = new Thread(new Producer());
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                  io.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;

            case Token.CONSUMER:
              t1 = new Thread(new Consumer());
              t1.start();
              try{t1.join();}
              catch(InterruptedException io)
              {
                  io.printStackTrace();
              }
            default:
              System.out.println("Wrong command.");
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is not about the java program. Is more about the thing you are trying to run here is the key `%1 is not a valid Win32 application` it seems you are trying to run `%1` as it was a program. And I don't think it is

Comment: I'm not to sure how that could be. I never typed %1 to run. I typed the class test.java or test.class to execute. Why is that notepad runs using the exec command without an issue?

Comment: Can you share how exactly are you trying to run this? Thanks!

Comment: I just posted the main class i use to run exec... I start main.java from command prompt. Inside command prompt I type exec "some Main class".class or .java, args[].

Comment: To run test.java I type "exec test.java x x x" where x is a number.

Comment: Remember that to execute a class from command line you must run it through the JVM: `java[.exe] <class name> [<arguments>]`.

Comment: @Little I'm not to sure about your convention "java[.exe]" can you elaborate?

Comment: exec java -cp Test.class 2 2 2 this kind of works. But I don't get the expected output I should be receiving from Test.class

Comment: Is there a good reason why your two java applications should communicate via `exec`? Why not just put them in the same `jar` and use much more convininet direct calls of methods?

Comment: `exec java -cp Test.class 2 2 2` outputs `2 2 2`. What output should we be getting?

Comment: It just prints out that program has run. It prints that because the argument that is used to create f = new File(), is a file. It should print "FFFF" while n <= 0. n will be arg[0]. But again, it doesn't print "FFFF", or even args[0-2].